# Vibration on Android

Tags: unity, android

How to change duration of vibration on Android(Unity3D)?

For example:

```
public void Jump()
{
    if (grounded)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, jumpPower);
        Handheld.Vibrate();
    }
}
```

This code makes a vibration in one second long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a plugin in asset store to regulate vibration. here's a link: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10982
or you can check this one it's FREE: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16648